# Malloc and Realloc array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, realloc

I am defining a type of structures

```
typedef struct structs{
int freeSpace;
} structs;
```

I am creating a pointer to a structure

```
structs* arrayOfStructs;
```

I am allocating memory for array of size 5 of that structure

```
arrayOfStructs = malloc(5 * sizeof (arrayOfStructs));
arrayOfStructs[3].freeSpace = 99;
printf("\n%d", arrayOfStructs[3].freeSpace);
```

At some point I am reallocating that memory to array of size 10

```
arrayOfStructs = realloc(arrayOfStructs, 10 * sizeof (arrayOfStructs));
arrayOfStructs[8].freeSpace = 9;
printf("\n%d", arrayOfStructs[8].freeSpace);
```

And here I am setting freespace 17 at position 13 of the array which I expect to have only 10 positions.

```
arrayOfStructs[13].freeSpace = 17;
printf("\n%d", arrayOfStructs[13].freeSpace);
free(arrayOfStructs);
```

Why is this working ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You are invoking undefined behavior - it's "working" because your compiler's implementation happens to produce that kind of code (Which may just be coincidental, change with changes to the code, be different on a different compiler, change with optimization level, ....)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour of the program is *undefined*.

You are accessing memory that doesn't belong to you.

(What could well be happening is that `realloc` is obtaining more memory from the operating system than is actually required).

Comment: does this mean that my code is correct, because here I see a different syntax for the same task   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169972/realloc-an-array-of-structs?rq=1

Comment: Your code is absolutely not correct. You can't access position 13 legally in a 10 element array.

Comment: Thank you ! This is what I needed