# C11 - Realloc on array of structs fails when doing realloc twice

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, realloc

I'm trying to use malloc and realloc to hold an array of structs. The array should dynamically grow, size should increase by 10 struct elements every time.

Struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char foreign_word_[100] = {0};
    unsigned char native_word_[100] = {0};
} VocabularyCouple;
```

In my main, I initialize the array with malloc:

```
VocabularyCouple* VocStruct = (VocabularyCouple*)malloc(sizeof(*VocStruct) * 10);
```

Increasing the size of the struct-array seems to work fine in main...

```
VocabularyCouple* temp = (VocabularyCouple*)realloc(VocStruct, (sizeof(VocabularyCouple) * 20));

if (temp == NULL)
{
    printf("ERROR: Out of Memory\n");
    return 4;
}
else
{
    VocStruct = temp;
    free(temp);
    temp = NULL;
}
```

However, if I put the realloc-part into a function like this:

```
uint8_t resizeVoc(uint32_t new_size, VocabularyCouple **VocStruct)
{
    VocabularyCouple *temp = (VocabularyCouple*)realloc(*VocStruct, (sizeof(VocabularyCouple) * new_size));
    ...
}
```

I can only call the function once. Every other call will result in this error:

```
HEAP[VocTest.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 01300000, 01308500 )
```

Unless I'm missing something, this should be the same problem as [c - Realloc an array of Structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169972/realloc-an-array-of-structs), but I just can't get it to work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please don't fix the code here, post a new question if needed.

Comment: Thank you so much, you solved my issue. I tried to set `VocStruct = &temp` instead of `*VocStruct = temp;`.

Comment: `typedef struct
{
    unsigned char foreign_word_[100] = {0};
    unsigned char native_word_[100] = {0};
} VocabularyCouple;` what language is it?

Answer (score 3):

```
VocStruct = temp;
free(temp);
```

This is wrong, you free all memory as soon as you have allocated it. `VocStruct` and `temp` point at the same memory area. Just remove the `free()`.

To clarify, the `temp` pointer is just there in case `realloc` fails. Had you written `VocStruct = realloc(VocStruct, ...` and `realloc` fails, then you would have overwritten the only pointer to the allocated memory with NULL and created a memory leak. But you only ever have 1 chunk of memory - even though 2 pointers point at it at the same time.

Comment: Oh right, what a stupid mistake. However, I didn't have the free() in the function so the problem remains.

Comment: @Heinzable Smells like undefined behavior though. It never worked fine in main(), it just seemed that way by bad luck. But you can fix that bug and then post a new question. Make sure it's a [mcve].

Comment: @Heinzable Perhaps you forgot to assign `*VocStruct = temp;` in your `resizeVoc` function, so the caller is still using the old, no longer valid memory location.